# How to use css in asp.net for web server control?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

In asp.net using a web server control but in visual studio why style attribute is not coming for the below code

```
  <asp:Label ID = "UserLabel" runat = "server" CssClass = "LabelClass" AssociatedControlID = "UsernameTextBox" >Username</asp:Label>
```

By intellisense it should come right, but style attribute is not coming at all.
I am using visual studio 2010 , asp.net using C#

Comment: What is the rendered HTML? And what is your corresponding stylesheet?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 , asp.net using c#

Comment: I would not use spaces between attributes for one. Could be a syntax issue.

Comment: By intellisense style attribute should come right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Style` property never shows on intellisense when using the asp server controls. The intellisense will show for the attributes after you type `Style="`

The server control inherits System.Web.UI.Control, which doesn't have `style` as a property.

However, it will be rendered out to the HTML.